# Running from Visual Studio - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - Angular, Net(5.0) app, Electron

Tags: c#, angular, electron, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I am running Visual Studio 2019. I have an **angular app** that **works completely fine when Electron is not running**. For example, **If I choose `IIS Express`** from the debug list, **all works well** (ApiControllers run correctly and return data):

[image]

However, **if I run with Electron.Net App**, the site loads and shows the page, but **my ApiControllers are not contactable**. The following error appears:

[image]

Here is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        // Registers a few services with their interfaces
        IOCContainer iocContainer = new IOCContainer();
        iocContainer.ConfigureServices(services);
        //

        // Is this needed?
        services.AddCors(options =>
            options.AddPolicy("DefaultCorsPolicy", builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()));

        // This is very important for some of the services I register in the iocContainer
        services.AddHttpClient();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        //app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            //endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            //    name: "api",
            //    pattern: "api/{controller}/{action}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

        ElectronBootstrap();
    }

    public async void ElectronBootstrap()
    {
        BrowserWindowOptions options = new BrowserWindowOptions
        {
            Show = false,
            //WebPreferences = new WebPreferences() {
            //    AllowRunningInsecureContent = true,
            //    ContextIsolation = false
            //}
        };
        BrowserWindow mainWindow = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync();
        mainWindow.OnReadyToShow += () =>
        {
            mainWindow.Show();
        };
        mainWindow.SetTitle("App Name here");
        mainWindow.WebContents.OpenDevTools();

        MenuItem[] menu = new MenuItem[]
        {
            new MenuItem
            {
                Label = "File",
                Submenu=new MenuItem[]
                {
                    new MenuItem
                    {
                        Label ="Exit",
                        Click =()=>{Electron.App.Exit();}
                    }
                }
            },
            new MenuItem
            {
                Label = "Info",
                Click = async ()=>
                {
                    await Electron.Dialog.ShowMessageBoxAsync("Welcome to App");
                }
            }
        };

        Electron.Menu.SetApplicationMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

and here is my Program.cs

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseElectron(args);
                    //webBuilder.UseSetting("https_port", "8080");
                });

        //public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        //    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        //.UseStartup<Startup>()
        //
    }
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong? I assume the IIS server is not running, but that would defy the point of having a self contained desktop application running on Electron. What options do I have?

**My goal:**

To have a self contained desktop application that others can use.

- It will read and write files from local file system.
- It will make requests out to APIs
- It will have an Angular front end and a C# back end.

**Additional info:**
This may be relevant:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can improve my question? Still stuck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with the default application set up in Visual Studio for Angular apps.
There is a "getBaseUrl" constant in the Angular/Typescript code module. If you use it in injection of your services, it will always route you through the full URL which may or may not be correct after packaging up your application. Instead, you can blank it out or simply not use it.

[image]